# Resetting update_geom_defaults() in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

This sounds so simple and I am sure it is...

If you use `ggplot2::update_geom_defaults()` such as:

```
ggplot2::update_geom_defaults("line", list(colour = 'red', linetype = 2))
```

How do you return ggplot2 to its original defaults?

So far all I have found is to check if `ggplot2` is loaded and if it is then detach and reload it therefore "resetting" the defaults, but that seems like a terrible hack.

```
  if("ggplot2" %in% (.packages())){
     suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(detach("package:ggplot2", unload=TRUE)))
     suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(library(ggplot2)))}
```

There must be an easier way.

Comment: If you're going to set new defaults and then reset them in the same R sessions, it seems to me you'd be better off simply modifying the aesthetics of your `ggplot()` call or making a new theme.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can "save" the defaults and then reapply them:

```
old <- ggplot2:::check_subclass("line", "Geom")$default_aes # 2018
old <- ggplot2:::find_subclass("Geom","line")$default_aes # pre 2.0 I think

> old 
* colour   -> "black"
* size     -> 0.5
* linetype -> 1
* alpha    -> NA

update_geom_defaults("line", list(color = "red"))

> ggplot2:::find_subclass("Geom","line")$default_aes
$color
[1] "red"

$colour
[1] "black"

$size
[1] 0.5

$linetype
[1] 1

$alpha
[1] NA
```

And then back:

```
update_geom_defaults("line", old)
```

This is clunky, in my opinion. You're much better off creating a plot function, or simply adding or removing `+ geom_line()`. The idea behind setting geom_defaults is to have defaults for the entire session.

Example plot function:

```
my_plotfun <- function(x, opt0, opt1, opt2, opt3) {
 p <- ggplot(x, aes(...))
 if(opt0) 
   p <- p + geom_line(...)
 if(opt1) 
   p <- p + coord_flip()
 if(opt2)
   ...
 p
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend `using update_geom_defaults()` inside a function. The usage pattern is more akin to something you would put into an `Rprofile.site` or perhaps an `.onLoad` function in a package if you had to apply a corporate theme or something of that nature. If you're doing this inside a function, much better is to adjust your plots in a sequence, I'll update my example function.

Comment: Nice. I agree this is clunky.

I have a function that has an option to add colour by a column in the data frame with `aes(col = column)` and if it is not present to be `aes(), col = 'red'`.

Changing defaults one way and back seems a better way than an 

`if() else()` statement with one with 

`geom_line(aes(col = column))` and `geom_line(aes(), col = 'red')` dependent on `missing(col)`.

Comment: Look at the example plot function above. Essentially, you just add layers based on conditions. This is a more typical approach.

Comment: `update_geom_defaults()` also comes in handy when using `autoplot()`

Comment: Function is now `check_subclass` with slightly different input order.